# WordPress: Importing multiple categories?

Tags: wordpress, import

I am working on a directory site based on Wordpress and I need to import categories and members from an existing website. WordPress currently has an importer tool that is said to allow imports of categories...but it's in the WXR format.

From my understanding, a WXR is a XML file, but I'm not sure the exact format to use for the category and member imports (if that is even possible).

I searched different sources for a solution to this but couldn't find anything.

I have over 70 categories and over 600 business members to import. I would appreciate any advice on importing multiple categories & members into WordPress.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Do you just need the categories, or the posts as well? Do you have direct database access on both servers?

Comment: I need the categories, but I think I found a solution. I exported a sample of the categories I created and based an import file on the same format of the exported file. Would the posts serve as member entries to the categories? I still need to import the members though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution to import multiple categories. I used the WordPress export and exported all the information from my site (posts, categories, ect). Then I carefully looked through the xml file and found the type of data I wanted to import (which was categories). So once I found the categories and its format, I removed everything else in between the ... tags, after the file details (titles, link, description, pubDate, generator, ect).

The category format is:

```
<wp:category><wp:category_nicename>"This is the Slug name" (no quotes</wp:category_nicename><wp:category_parent>"This is the parent name, optional" (no quotes)</wp:category_parent><wp:cat_name><![CDATA["This is the Category name" (no quotes)]]></wp:cat_name></wp:category>
```

You would create as many of this example as you need and just change the required information for the import. I think this strategy can also be used for other data to import. You would just have to examine the structure of the data in the original xml exported file and basically copy what you see.

Im still open to other techniques to import data. I hope this helps someone with importing needs.